# If strings starts with in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, startswith

Is there a way to check if a string starts with a string?

We are checking the groupmembership from the [AD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_Directory) user. Our AD groups look like this: `S_G_share1_W`

The script for connecting the networkshares should only run if the groupname starts with `"S_G_"`, because we have some other groups too.

```
$GroupArray = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $env:USERNAME | select samaccountname

foreach ($Group in $GroupArray) {

    if ($Group.StartsWith("S_G_")) {

        $Group = $Group -replace "S_G_", $FileServerRV
        Write-Host $Group

        $Group = $Group.Substring(0, $Group.Length-2)
        Write-Host $Group

        #erstellen des Anzeigennames
        $Groupname = $Group.Replace($FileServerRV, "")
        Write-Host "Call Function with parameter "$Group $Groupname
    }
}
```

Comment: `$Group.StartsWtih("string")`

Comment: Answer shows how to use startswith which is what you are asking for.

Comment: It's wright, that your answer provides a link to "How to use the StartsWith() function", but the problem which @JocSch has in this case is, that he tries to use the `StartsWith()` function on the object $Group and not on the acutal property of this object which is `$Group.samaccountname`

Answer (score 91, accepted):

`$Group` is an object, but you will actually need to check if `$Group.samaccountname.StartsWith("string")`.

Change `$Group.StartsWith("S_G_")` to `$Group.samaccountname.StartsWith("S_G_")`.