# Regular Expression - Replace multiple lines w/ same number of blank lines

Tags: regex, notepad++

Is it possible using regular expressions to to replace multiple lines w/ the same number of blank lines?

In context, I need to be able to change the following:

```
01    /*------------------------------------
02    Some history stuff goes here
03    Some history stuff goes here
04    Some history stuff goes here
05    Some history stuff goes here
06    Some history stuff goes here
07    --------------------------------------*/
08    int main void()
09    {
10       printf("Hello, World!");
11
12       return 0;
13    }
```

Into the following:

```
01    
02    
03    
04    
05    
06    
07    
08    int main void()
09    {
10       printf("Hello, World!");
11
12       return 0;
13    }
```

Right now I only have the following regex pattern, but it only replaces lines 01-07 with a single line:

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
(. matches newline checked)
```

If it helps, Im using Notepad++'s Find in Files feature since I need to do it in multiple files in a folder.

Comment: @sweaver2112 "ff" is shortcut for "following"

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866034/removing-empty-lines-in-notepad#20953496) ?

Comment: @STIKO thanks but Im not trying to remove "empty lines" im trying to replace "block comments" with the same number of "blank lines"

Comment: i think you'd need a few script commands to get this done, regex doesn't offer a "number of lines matched" variable in the substitution.

Comment: @sweaver2112 any suggestions how to get started?

Comment: use the first pattern, then against that commented text, match again against `/.*\n/` to see how many lines you have, insert that many newlines, or something like that. (virtually any language/shell would work, don't' know what your env is)

Comment: @slimjourney I don't think you can get the number of lines, but you could replace the whole comment section using this `^/\*[-]*[^\*/]*\*/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `notpad++` I'm assuming you're on windows. You may need to use power shell to achieve this.
First read the file line by line, found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192072/how-to-process-a-file-in-powershell-line-by-line-as-a-stream#4192419)

```
$reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText("my.log")
while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
    $line
}
```

Then do some logic when the line starts with `/*` and ends with `*/`, source [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654569/powershell-if-strings-starts-with#35654705)

```
$Group.StartsWith("/*")
```

Answer (score 1):

This perl one-liner does the job:

```
perl -ne 'if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\//) {print "\n"} else {print}' file > output
```

under windows, change single quotes with double quotes

```
perl -ne "if (/\/\*/ .. /\*\//) {print \"\n\"} else {print}" file > output
```